# typescript generic type htmlelement wrap

Tags: generics, typescript

i tried to do that but this.element cannot be assigned to  i don't understand why

```
class Elem<T> {
    public element : T;
    constructor(typeElement:string){
        this.element = document.createElement(typeElement);
    }
}
```

as you can see [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=interface%20Sprite%20extends%20HTMLElement%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20createSprite%28%29%20%3A%20Sprite%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%3CSprite%3E%20document.createElement%28%22div%22%29;%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20sprite%20=%20createSprite%28%29;%0D%0Asprite.innerHTML%20=%20%27Test%27;%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild%28sprite%29;)

Comment: "i tried to do that" - what's *that*?

Comment: probably the code below, right? it's not a dissertation thesis, people understand when they understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is pretty close, the only issue is that T should represent that it extends HTMLElement and then you have to cast HTMLElement to type T (not sure why) in side the constructor.

```
//         cast T as type HTMLElement
class Elem<T extends HTMLElement> {
    public element: T;
    constructor(typeElement: string) {
        // had to cast HTMLElement to type T....
        // odd because T extends HTMLElement, but it works
        this.element = <T>document.createElement(typeElement);
    }
}

var e = new Elem('div');
e.element.innerHTML = 'generic class test';
document.body.appendChild(e.element);
```

You can see it working in the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=interface%20Sprite%20extends%20HTMLElement%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20createSprite()%20%3A%20Sprite%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%3CSprite%3E%20document.createElement(%22div%22)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20sprite%20%3D%20createSprite()%3B%0D%0Asprite.innerHTML%20%3D%20'Test'%3B%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild(sprite)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Elem%3CT%20extends%20HTMLElement%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20element%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(typeElement%3A%20string)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.element%20%3D%20%3CT%3Edocument.createElement(typeElement)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20e%20%3D%20new%20Elem('div')%3B%0D%0Ae.element.innerHTML%20%3D%20'generic%20class%20test'%3B%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild(e.element)%3B)

Comment: I believe this is not going all the way. `e.element` is a basic `HTMLElement`, unless you specify `new Elem<HTMLDivElement>("div")`. But that means that one could write `new Elem<HTMLDivElement>("body")` or any other wrong combination. The compiler won't argue. Try setting a property not in basic `HTMLElement` (e.g. `align`) and it won't compile.